# Applying Middleware to a specific route

Tags: php, laravel

Simple question but i'm quite new to Laravel.

I've got my middleware function attached to my dish controller at the top, however i want it attached to my dish/create route specifically.

```
function __construct() { 
    $this->middleware('auth:restaurantuser');
}
```

I thought in theory this would work, but it doesn't.

```
public function create()
{
    function __construct() { 
        $this->middleware('auth:restaurantuser');
    }

    return view('dishes.create')->with('restaurants', Restaurant::all());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the middleware in your specific route.

```
Route::get('dishes/create', 'DishesController@create')->name('dishes.create')->middleware('auth:restaurantuser');
```

Answer (score 0):

Middleware for Route In Web file:

```
Route::get('dishes/create', 'DishesController@create')->name('dishes.create')->middleware('auth:restaurantuser');
```

Remove your middleware from constructor..

```
public function create()
{
   return view('dishes.create')->with('restaurants', Restaurant::all());
}
```

for more detail go to this link
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes